# Ionic v1 lock app so user can't exit (kiosk mode?)

Tags: android, angularjs, mobile, ionic-framework

I have a major problem with my Ionic App (version 1). It's a Satisfaction survey on android 4.4.2 and I don't want users to be able to leave the app. I need to disable home and back button. I know there is something like Kiosk mode but I don't know how to set my app to run in such mode. I've seen many threads and still have no solution for my problem. I would use some third party app but they are all quite expensive and I have about 100 tablets to run the app. Do you guys have any ideas? How to lock my app so user can only leave it by entering the password for instance. Please help me, I'm struggling third day with this.

Comment: this link will definitely help you http://www.andreas-schrade.de/2015/02/16/android-tutorial-how-to-create-a-kiosk-mode-in-android/

Comment: The problem is it's Ionic app, not Native Android

Comment: Maybe this -> https://github.com/hkalina/cordova-plugin-kiosk